# Azure DevOps re-connect repository to existing folder

Tags: azure-devops

I have a number of projects in Azure DevOps that are saved through Visual Studio to my local drive. I just went through removing Visual Studio Community from my computer and installing Professional instead as I have a license. I am trying to reconnect all my local cloned folders to azure in the Team Explorer window.

I can't see any way to just re-set up the binding. In manage connections I can see all my projects, but the only option available is to choose a new empty folder and clone/download all the source code again.

Is there any way to just re-establish the connection from DevOps to my local folders??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to open the local sln file in Visual Studio Professional.

[image]

Click on the option shown in the figure below, and you will find that there is already a connection between the cloned local repo and the remote repo.

[image]

[image]

In Team Explorer, you only need to connect to the repo.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I think I was partially confused by the recent Visual Studio update that moved some of the Team Explorer stuff to the GIT window if you are just using Azure DevOps as a GIT repository. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my solution would not even load the project in VS Professional 2022 after upgrading from VS Community 2022. I had to uninstall everything and then reinstall VS Professional 2022 and then everything reconnected automatically.

Visual Studio Installer:
[image]